# print expect output to the terminal on the fly

Tags: tcl, expect

I want to run some script on other machine, by doing ssh there. This script might take longer time and it would be better for me if I am able to display what is going on right now in execution step.
But, when I pass to spawn ssh with script, task is completed and it comes out silently. Is there a way that we can print the output from the other machine. I can take a log also, but it can be accessed when job is completed. Can I do it on the fly?

```
package require Expect
spawn ssh machine
expect -regexp {
    "bash" {
        send "perl script.pl\r"
    }
    timeout {
        exit
    }
    eof {
        exit
    }
    interact
}
puts "Done"
```

I have used, `puts $expect_out(buffer);` which is giving me no variable error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That `interact` looks fishy, and you're not `expect`ing anything after the `send`…

Comment: Can you simply do this from your shell: `ssh machine perl script.pl`